# adjust the size of my textview in stackview and blank spaces

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uistackview

I have a stack view in my scroll view and there are 3 views in my stack. (arranged subviews)
The second of them is a text view if my text is not long there may some blank space on my screen I guess I did some mistakes. How can I remove this space and what should be my view's size?
I want to adjust them.

(yellow one is my textview(akor_goster) , blue one is my bannerview for admob)

here is my code

```
       let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    
       let scrollView = UIScrollView()

       scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
       scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
       scrollView.isDirectionalLockEnabled = false
     
       return scrollView
   }()

   let stackView: UIStackView = {
    
       let view = UIStackView()
   
       view.axis = .vertical
       view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
       return view
   }()

   let firstView: UIView = {
    
       let view = UIView()

       view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4392156899, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1)
    
       view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 125).isActive = true
    
       return view
   }()

   let banner: UIView = {
    
       let view = UIView()

    view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1411764771, green: 0.3960784376, blue: 0.5647059083, alpha: 1)
       return view
   }()
   
   
   let akor_goster: UITextView = {
    
       let view = UITextView()

       view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411793, green: 0.6862745285, blue: 0.1333333403, alpha: 1)
       view.textAlignment = .left
       view.textColor = .black
       
    
       view.isEditable = false
       view.isScrollEnabled = false
   
       return view
   }()

       view.addSubview(scrollView)

       scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
       scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    
       stackView.addArrangedSubview(firstView)
       stackView.addArrangedSubview(akor_goster)
       stackView.addArrangedSubview(banner)
    

    
       akor_goster.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    
       scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.akor_goster.frame.width, height: self.akor_goster.frame.height)

       scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
       scrollView.bounces = true
       
       scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
       scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
       scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
       scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

       stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
       stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
       stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
       stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
            
       banner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
       banner.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
       banner.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
       banner.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
       banner.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
         
       bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

       
       bannerView.adUnitID = AdmobId.bannerId
       bannerView.rootViewController = self
       
       addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
       bannerView.load(GADRequest())

       bannerView.delegate = self
```

[image: my screen]

Comment: Do you want your "banner view" to **always** be visible, "pinned" to the top of the tabBar? Or, do you want it to start at the top of the tabBar, and if your textView gets too tall, it should "push" the banner view down (so you have to scroll up to see it again)?

Comment: @DonMag I want to see my banner view at the bottom of the my screen when I do this , I guess it looks better what do you think.

Comment: If you want your banner at the bottom, take it out of the scroll view... constrain it to the bottom of safe-area... constrain the bottom of your scroll view to the top of the banner.

Comment: I pinned to bottom of my view as subview and I gave 50 height,then I decrease 50 my scrollview from bottom now it looks better :)